# Change thumbnail size in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I tried to find it using google, but there are only tips for 2007.

I want to change a few layout things, which are:

- The thumbnail size of an image library
- The thumbnail size in a slide library

I found this good explanation here:

http://vspug.com/keutmann/2007/01/27/how-to-resize-the-thumbnails-in-a-picture-library/

But I can't find the screenshot view (these nice options) anywhere inside my Sharepoint Designer. Its 2010, so maybe they moved it somewhere else. Anyone has an idea where to find this options tab from the screenshot?

Thanks a lot, 
Chris

Answer (score 1):

The linked article does not describe SharePoint ***Designer***, but rather SharePoint ***Manager***, which appears to be a third party tool created by the author.

You could give it a try. Like the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx), it might still work for SharePoint 2010, especially if it uses web services to connect to the site.

But if it doesn't, you should be able to write a Feature Receiver that will accomplish the same thing by modifying the [ThumbnailSize property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sppicturelibrary.thumbnailsize%28v=office.12%29.aspx). That has to be what the SharePoint Manager tool is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding changing the thumbnail size of the Slide Library (which you cannot use Sharepoint Manager to do unlike the picture library)

This worked for me to get a bigger thumbnail..

Note that the solution relies on having a naming convention for your files which you apply after you have loaded them up to the slide library eg `ENG_02_0010`, `ENG_02_0020` rather than leaving them named as is when uploaded to Sharepoint.

1. Create another field called Preview say and make it a picture (format url as picture)
2. For each uploaded slide put the url link as `http://siteName/slidelibraryName/_t/ENG_02_0010_pptx.jpg` (same name as your slide with a `_pptx.jpg` extension)
3. Get rid of the standard thumbnail from your view and put this new column next to the selection box

Worked for me, much bigger and readable thumbnail!

PS
In SP designer you can find all the jpg thumbnails in the `_t` directory under the slide library

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS on the page where you're displaying the thumbnail images. Here is an example:

`<style type="text/css">
img[alt="Thumbnail"] {height:100% !Important;width:100% !Important;}
</style>`

This looks for the images with an alt attribute of 'Thumbnail'. I successfully tested this with a Slide library in SharePoint 2013 using IE & Chrome.